# r barplot that displays sums of values of y for each x

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am trying to produce a barplot that shows each of the four surgeons on the x-axis and the sum of each one's surgery durations on the y-axis, help is much appreciated. "Surgeon" is character type and "Duration" is 'times' type from the chron package.

Sample Data:

```
Surgeon Duration
Jack    00:22:00
Ben     00:34:00
Charles 03:12:00
Hank    01:15:00
Jack    00:59:00
Ben     00:44:00
Hank    01:46:00
Hank    00:32:00
Ben     00:49:00
Ben     06:19:00
Charles 07:02:00
Jack    00:58:00
Jack    00:21:00
```

Comment: What have you tried? There must be a thousand `aggregate` and `sum by group` questions for R on this site. `barplot()` is ultimately your end point for plotting, as I hope you've already guessed. Try something like: `barplot(with(dat, tapply(Duration, Surgeon, sum) ))` for starters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have an input file called `Input.txt` which contains the data in your question, this will get you pretty close. For your reference, you should look at the [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/chron/chron.pdf) to learn how to get stuff out of the `chron` object.

```
# Aggregation
library(chron)
data = read.table("Input.txt", header=T, as.is =c(T,T))
data$Duration = chron(times=data$Duration)
processed = aggregate(Duration ~ Surgeon, data, sum)
print(processed)

# This will do total seconds, but you can change it to whatever you want to plot.
total_seconds = hours(processed$Duration) * 3600 +  minutes(processed$Duration) * 60 + seconds(processed$Duration)
barplot(total_seconds, names.arg=processed$Surgeon)
```

Comment: Why do the multiplication for each component separately? Wouldn't just multiplying the days out be okay? I.e. - `with(dat, tapply(Duration, Surgeon, sum))*86400`

Comment: @thelatemail, I have not tested that, but I wrote it in the most readable way I could think of first. :)